# Low-quality answer with great comment

Tags: discussion, comments, low-quality-posts

I ran across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5112564) while reviewing low-quality posts. The answer itself

- looks pretty much like link-only;
- has 0 score for three years compared to the accepted answer with a score of 62,

and therefore (presumably) should be voted to delete. However, there's a comment to it that

- explains why the proposed solution may be misleading;
- has 20 upvotes, meaning it turned out to be useful for those who tried these links.

Since the comment itself is more valuable than the answer, I skipped voting on this. But I'm still curious what is considered to be the right action for this (extraordinary) case.

Comment: You can't close an answer, it can only be deleted.  Which wipes out the comment as well.  While not helpful, there's an implicit usefulness about knowing to *avoid* a solution, particularly if it is common misconception.  Looks like this is such a case, don't delete it.

Comment: @HansPassant Why don't you post that as an answer? :)

Comment: I don't know the subject so this is just opinion, not an answer :)

Comment: Or rather, include the comment in the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: The link the comment is referring to is a 404. There's room for improvement.

Comment: It's silly to think that's a **bad answer**.  It's written by an expert, it has critical information.  Often when people, experts, answer quite obvious questions, they just stuff in a very quick answer, with a few links.  Regarding the silly policy (this week) on SO that "links are bad", whatever.  Click edit and add some text.  Regarding the spirit of your question, I'd say no, never delete an answer where there is a super-useful comment. It would be crazy to erase important info, because of some naive policy that isn't thought out and doesn't cover that situation.

Comment: Click edit and add some text indeed.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If the comment contains important information that is missing from other answers, I would edit the bad answer to include the information in the comment, thus turning it into a good-quality answer and preventing the comment from being buried by any downvotes on the answer.

Comment: If I was reviewing that kind of an edit where you added the comment to the post itself I would consider that an invalid edit and reject the edit. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Lynda: No, you're not. I'd expect users with editing privileges to make that edit. In fact, I've edited it now.

Comment: And so possibly let the answerer gather upvotes for the efforts of other contributors. Seems not so fair, too. But I don't see any better, either.

Answer (score 12):

I realize that this doesn't answer the general question you're posing, but as to the specifics of the linked answer...

You're misunderstanding the situation. The highly-rated comment is a caveat about the answer - it warns that one of the things the answer suggests (`validates_associated`, specifically) doesn't work the way the answer suggests.

In this case, the comment has value only in the sense that the answer would be worse without it. It is not, in itself, an answer to the question, and if the answer it was on went away, it would no longer be necessary.

Answer (score 9):

You could edit the poor answer with details from the great comment but I feel that such an action would unduly benefit the poor author.

I believe that mods can convert/migrate a comment to an answer so I would give the comment a custom flag requesting that and then edit it after to shape it to fit as a stand alone answer. This would give the rep to the actual deserving author.

Comment: I don't think comments can be converted to answers. The reverse is possible, though.

Comment: It doesn't really matter who is rewarded. All that matters is that we have good answers.

Comment: I respect that view and wish it could be held by all but awarding points to people that hunt them, for low quality posts only encourages laziness and lowers the bar for what is the perceived  bar for acceptable material. I don't think it lends itself to increasing the quality of the overall site.

Comment: As I said in my own answer to this question, it's important to consider whether anybody else has already written the same answer. If two people have answered with the same thing, but one is better written/has more details, obviously the better one should be supported as much as possible. But if the *only* answer is brief, then I don't see any problem with helping that person out a bit. Presumably they're one of the few people who's actually familiar with the problem and whatever tiny amount of time they're able to contribute should be rewarded.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert  Exactly. This is such an edge case that I doubt it will lead to any "gaming" of the system, or laziness in providing good answers. And in case some reputation points become misdirected: as you say, the point of Stack Exchange is to discover good answers.

Answer (score 7):

Your analysis of the options available is pretty spot on. However, I disagree with your opinion that it is a link-only answer. Remove all the links from the answer, and check — does it answer the question? I'm no RoR expert, but I think it does. It suggests an available option, and links to the relevant documentation, and the project's GitHub page. It may not be very useful, but it's useful additional information, and it *answers* the question. Thus, it should not be deleted.

The comment below that answer points out a caveat with using `validates_associated`, and the upvotes on that comment indicate that people apparently found it useful — which they wouldn't have, if the answer wasn't there. This valuable information would be lost if the answer is gone.

The commenter didn't choose to post it as an answer, probably because it doesn't actually answer the question. However, it is useful information. Comments are meant to be second-class citizens anyway, so editing it into the answer is the best thing to do (of course, only if it's relevant and useful to the answer). I've gone ahead and [made the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5690022/1438393) now.

Comment: I agree otherwise, but I think the original link(s) should be preserved, because they might prove useful to people looking for more information.